# ASP.NET Core - Get absolute URL to Razor page from background service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core application using .NET 7 and Razor pages.

As part of the app, we have a background task (IHostedService) which runs periodically and sends an email which should include an absolute URL to a specific page in the app.

Normally, using dependency injection, we can accomplish this by using e.g. `Url.PageLink("/MyPage")`.

However, the "Url" (of type `IUrlHelper`) is not available in the background task.
If I try to inject a `IUrlHelper` into the background task, it will either throw an exception, or the link generated will be incorrect.

Right now the workaround is that when a user visits the page in queston, we save the absolute url using `Url.PageLink` in a static variable. Obviously this is a bad solution since it requires a user to visit the page before we're able to generate the correct URL.

So, how do we generate a correct absolute url to any page from anywhere in the application?

Comment: From your description, since the background task is running periodically, and it is running in the background, why you want to generate the url to any page from anywhere in the application? One scenario I can think of is there is a button on the page (any page in the application), when clicked it, it will record the current request path, and then sends an email to this path when the background service runs. If that is the case, you can save the url in database, Azure Queue Storage and so on. Then, access them in the background service.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `[System.Threading.Channels][1]`. Here is a simple example on how to use it and send your Url to the  background task: https://flerka.github.io/personal-blog/2020-01-23-communication-with-hosted-service-using-channels/